# разница между получением данных напрямую и с помощью геттера

Tags: angularjs

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в поведении ангуляра.

Есть сервис:

```
myApp.factory('myService', function($http){
    var obj = [];

    function init () {
        return $http.get('test.php').
        then(function(answ) {
            obj = answ;
        });
    }

    function getObj () {
        return obj;
    }

return {
    init: init,
    obj1: obj,
    obj2: getObj
}
})
```

И есть контроллер, который работает с этим сервисом:

```
myApp.controller('myController',
    function myController($scope, myService){
        console.log('0.0 ' + myService.obj1);
        console.log('0.1 ' + myService.obj2());

        myService.obj1 = ['test'];

        console.log('1.0 ' + myService.obj1);
        console.log('1.1 ' + myService.obj2());

        myService.init()
        .then(function() {
            console.log('2.0 ' + myService.obj1);
            console.log('2.1 ' + myService.obj2());

             myService.obj1 = ['test1'];

            console.log('3.0 ' + myService.obj1);
            console.log('3.1 ' + myService.obj2());
        });
```

В консоль в результате будет выведено:

```
0.0
0.1
1.0 test
1.1 test
2.0 test
2.1 [*данные от сервера*]
3.0 test1
3.1 [*данные от сервера*]
```

Не могу понять, почему так происходит.
Получается вначале obj1 и obj2 ссылаются на одни и те же данные, причём через obj1 их можно изменять и obj2 эти изменения заметит, но после того, как данные в сервисе изменяются самим сервисом, obj1 продолжает ссылаться на старый вариант данных, а obj2 на новый вариант, и изменения данных через obj1 не видны в obj2 (и наоборот. Если ввести ещё и сеттер, менять данные через него, то изменения будут видны в obj2 и не видны в obj1).

Почему obj1 продолжает ссылаться на старый объект?

Comment: а вы уверены, что для приведенного лога - первое изменение было присваиванием, а не вызовом `push` например?

Comment: Уже не уверен. Я там долго разные варианты пробовал, мог и запутаться. Собственно, даже если первым и был пуш, ситуация понятнее не становится. Почему, если и в первом и во втором случае мы получаем ссылку на один и тот же массив, после получения и обработки данных от $http, внезапно, прямая ссылка так и указывает на старый массив, а геттер начинает возвращать ссылку на новый массив?

Comment: хотя... Наверное понял. Если бы я в сервисе делал не obj = answ; а, например, obj.push(answ), то разницы бы не возникало, правильно?

Comment: да, так как в этом случае obj и obj1 продолжили бы ссылаться на один объект.

Answer (score 1):

После

```
myService.obj1 = ['test'];
```

myService.obj1 уже указывает на другой, вновь созданный массив из одного значения 'test'. Соответственно далее идет разный вывод от myService.obj1 и myService.obj2()

Правда это не стыкуется с вашим логом:

```
0.0
0.1
1.0 test
1.1 test
2.0 test
2.1 [*данные от сервера*]
3.0 test1
3.1 [*данные от сервера*]
```

Конкретно с четвертой строкой, где ожидается пустая строка. [Ссылка](https://plnkr.co/edit/lYDsJLnDuefaAGujZ5Xr?p=preview) на Plunker.

Comment: Вот этот момент мне не понятен. Почему myService.obj1 = ['test']; не изменяет массив в сервисе? Получается у сервиса после этого действия становится 2 свойства с одинаковым именем? Более того, если я вместо присвоения сделаю пуш, то картина ни как не изменится. Эксперименты показали, что разделение информации происходит в момент получения данных из $http запроса

Comment: **myService.obj1 = ['test'];** делает то же, что **myService.obj1 = new Array('test');** т.е. создает новый массив, и присваивает ссылку на него полю myService.obj1. Исходный массив, на который ранее хранилась ссылка в myService.obj1 продолжает существовать, его вы получаете с помощью getObj.

Comment: Если вам действительно нужно изменить значение исходного массива, то вместо myService.obj1 = ['test'];  можно попробовать myService.obj1.length = 0; myService.obj1.push('test');

Comment: Вот именно с пуша всё и началось. Пуш вроде бы изменил исходный массив, я решил, что всё работает как я задумал, подгрузил данные с сервера и не увидел их в массиве. Стал разбираться и пришёл к выводу, что после обработки http запроса данные, полученные из геттера соответствуют загруженным, а данными, полученными напрямую каким-то образом "отслаиваются" и продолжают жить своей жизнью. Надо бы посмотреть, что будет, если я обращусь к this.obj из сервиса. Но пока некогда.

Answer (score 0):

Частично сам себе отвечу.
Я был уверен, что сервис посредством return {obj1: obj} возвращает ссылку на переменную obj, а не её значение. На сколько я понимаю, я был не прав. 
Не понятным остаётся, почему после первого изменения данных у меня не было расхождения в myService.obj1 и myService.obj2(). Собственно это меня и сбило с толку.

Comment: на самом деле он ссылку и возвращает :-)

Comment: Так какого же тогда? Только мне показалось, что я что-то начал понимать, как на тебе! :)

Comment: Смотри соседний ответ: сначала ты сохраняешь ссылку на `obj` в поле объекта `obj1` - когда ты обращаешься к свойствам. например `length`, `push` и т.д. - они вызывались у `obj`, так как obj1 - ссылался на него, но как только ссылка была заменена `myService.obj1 = ['test'];` -  nj то теперь все операции проводятся с массивом `['test']`, при этом `obj` как был так и остался внутри, и его всегда возвращает метод.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Для понимания работы можно отследить на что ссылаются нужные объекты на каждом этапе.

```
myApp.factory('myService', function($http){
    var obj = []; // при инициализации ссылается на пустой массив;

    function init () {
        return $http.get('test.php').
        then(function(answ) {
            obj = answ; // после присваивания ссылается на ответ от сервера
        });
    }

    function getObj () {
        return obj; // возвращает значение на которое ссылается obj
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        obj1: obj, // сохраняем ссылку на obj
        obj2: getObj
    };
})
```

Теперь по пунктам в контроллере:

```
myApp.controller('myController',
    function myController($scope, myService){
        console.log('0.0 ' + myService.obj1); // ссылка на obj -> []
        console.log('0.1 ' + myService.obj2()); // возвращает obj -> []

        myService.obj1.push('test'); // обновляем значение по ссылке. добавляя в массив на который ссылаемся элемент

        console.log('1.0 ' + myService.obj1); // -> ['test']
        console.log('1.1 ' + myService.obj2()); // -> ['test']

        myService.init()
        .then(function() {
            // в этот блок попадаем после присваивания в функции init,
            console.log('2.0 ' + myService.obj1); // obj1 - ссылается на старый массив, так как при присваивании значения переменной obj - она стала ссылаться на новый массив, а obj1 - не изменился -> ['test']
            console.log('2.1 ' + myService.obj2()); // возвращает то, что присвоили -> [полученные данные]

             myService.obj1 = ['test1']; // замена ссылки в obj1 -> ['test1']

            console.log('3.0 ' + myService.obj1); // -> ['test1']
            console.log('3.1 ' + myService.obj2()); // -> [полученные данные]
        });
```

Так как при присвоении значения в функции init переменная `obj` стала ссылаться на новый массив, а obj1 - продолжила ссылаться на старый - имеем расхождение.